# how to change digits

Tags: arrays, c

theres a scanned number by user , i need to take all the digits and move them once to the right ,
next line move them to the left , for example if the number is 1234 , the first line will be 4123,
the next line after will be 2341 (once to the right and once to the left).
i built 2 function first determines how many digits there are in a number , the 2nd function divides the number into digits . i think the best way is to place the  digits in an array .
i've got a couple of problems:

- how can i set a variable in an array's size ??
- how can i place the digits in an array if i do not know the size and how to refer to the last index of an array (i couldnt find an .length() function in C )..

**Here's the code:**

```
int checkdigits(int num)
{
    int counter = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        num /= 10;
        counter++;

        if (num >= 0 && num < 1)
            break;

    }
    return counter;
}
int * separateNumbers(int num , int num2)
{
    int array[10];
    int finalnum = 1;
    for (int i = 2;i <= num;i++)
        finalnum = finalnum * 10;
    
    for (int i = 0;i < num; i++)
    {
        if (num2 / finalnum > 0 && num2 / finalnum < 10)
        {
            int v =  num2 / finalnum;
            array[i] = v;
            
        }
        else if ( finalnum >= 10)
        {
            
            int v = num2 / finalnum;
            
            
            v = v % 10;
            array[i] = v;
            
        }
        else if (finalnum < 10)
        {   
            int v = num2 % 10;
            array[i] = v;
            
        }

        finalnum = finalnum / 10;
    }
    
    return array;
    
}
void both() 
{
    int a;
    puts("please enter a number");
    scanf_s("%d",&a);
    int b =checkdigits(a);
    separateNumbers(b, a);
    

}
void changenumbers(int ar[])// this is the part i couldnt go further 
{
    int str;
    for(int i = 0;i<ar.length-1;)
    ar[i] = ar[];
    
}
int main(void)
{
    
    both();
    
    _getch();
return (1);
}
```

Comment: Make the array length the max you need for an int, and you will have to keep track of the indexes you placed numbers in yourself.

Comment: The `separateNumbers` function returns a pointer to a ***local*** variable. As such the life-time of the local variable will end as the function returns, meaning the pointer you return will become invalid immediately.

Comment: You can also use character array instead of integer to store the number's digits. And then shift to left or right within the character array.